# Type error in PyMySQL cursor

Tags: mysql, python-3.x, pymysql

I have the following simple code to test my Python Mysql connection.

```
connection = pymysql.connect(host = "localhost",
                     user = "root",
                     passwd = "",
                     db = "bugs",
                     charset = "utf8mb4",
                     cursorclass = "pymysql.cursors.Dictcursor")

try:
    with connection.cursor() as cur:
        cur.execute('''SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tbl_firefox''')

        for row in cur.fetchall():
            print("Number of rows in firefox table:", row)
    connection.commit()
finally:
    connection.close()
```

When I run the code I get a type error

```
File "test2.py", line 31, in <module>
    with connection.cursor() as cur:
  File "C:\Program Files\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pymysql\connections.py", line 833, in cursor
    return self.cursorclass(self)
TypeError: 'str' object is not callable
```

I have been viewing similar errors in other python-mysql codes. But still no luck. If anyone could point me the bug, much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quoted fro [PyMySQL](https://github.com/PyMySQL/PyMySQL):

```
import pymysql.cursors

# Connect to the database
connection = pymysql.connect(host='localhost',
                             user='user',
                             password='passwd',
                             db='db',
                             charset='utf8mb4',
                             cursorclass=pymysql.cursors.DictCursor)

try:
    with connection.cursor() as cursor:
        # Create a new record
        sql = "INSERT INTO `users` (`email`, `password`) VALUES (%s, %s)"
        cursor.execute(sql, ('webmaster@python.org', 'very-secret'))

    # connection is not autocommit by default. So you must commit to save
    # your changes.
    connection.commit()

    with connection.cursor() as cursor:
        # Read a single record
        sql = "SELECT `id`, `password` FROM `users` WHERE `email`=%s"
        cursor.execute(sql, ('webmaster@python.org',))
        result = cursor.fetchone()
        print(result)
finally:
    connection.close()
```

It should be password other than passwd and cursorclass is not surrounded by quotes

Comment: Rookie mistake from my end. Thanks a lot.